# Interior for a notebook

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, publishing

I am trying to make an interior for a notebook and I can't figure out how to duplicate one page across one hundred pages. I'm trying to find the easiest way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5):

This can be solved by using the **Master page template** feature in InDesign. First open a new InDesign document and set up your document to have the number of pages you'd like the document to have (this case it sounds like you'd like 100). In the **Pages Panel**, simply edit the **A-Master** section that appears at the top of the panel:

[image]

Select the **A-Master** page and place the notebook background you wish to use in the **A-Master** page spread, `right-click` the A-Master spread and select **Apply Master to Pages**:

[image]

In the **Apply Master** prompt, be sure to select **All Pages** in the **To Pages** drop down menu:

[image]

**Select OK** and the Master template will be applied across all pages in the document.